# How to define a constant for a model in Mongoid model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, model, mongoid, constants

Where to put here a constant definition to access it only with `MyModel.MYCONSTANT` or from any document of MyModel?

```
class MyModel

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  MYCONSTANT = "MYCONSTANT_VALUE"

end
```

Or should I use the `self`?

Answer (score 0):

That is fine to define a constant. However to access the constant you need to do this

`MyModel::MYCONSTANT`